# Control system on matlab

Tags: matlab

A satellite is launched for an astronomical mission, for which it needs to points its scientific sensor package in a specific direction. A simplified linearzed mathematical model of the above satellite is given below
$$g(s)=\frac{k(s)}{T(s)}=\frac{0.036(s+25)}{s^2(s^2+0.04s+1)}$$
It is desired that when effecting a change in altitude, the new altitude must be achiveable within 20 seconds and must not have the maximam overshoot of more than 15%, where  $k(s) =$ altitude angle and $T(s) =$ control torque. Solve by using matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can use sisotool gui (SISO Design Tool GUI)

in command window :

```
n=[0.036 0.036*25];                          
d=conv([1 0 0],[1 0.04 1]);
G=tf(n,d);
sisotool(G)
```

then >> SISO Design for SISO Design Task >> Analysis >> Response to step Command

in this window you can see step response of system , and you can add pole/zero to system and watch changes in step response.
[image: SISO Tool]